# Return an array of the repeated numbers

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, function, sorting

I have a sorted array and i want to return an array of just the repeated numbers 
array1 = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6] 
the output would be [2,5,6] 
what am i missing? i used javascript but you can use java too if you prefer

```
var findRepeated = function(numbers) {
    array = []
    for (var i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++){
        if(numbers[i] == numbers[i+1])
            array.push(numbers[i])
    }
    return array
};
```

Comment: "[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6] the output would be [1,2,3,4,5,6] " you mean you want to return an array of unique numbers instead of saying I want to return an array of duplicates!

Comment: the odd thing is, the code you've posted does exactly what your title says

Comment: as far as using java if you prefer, java and javascript are completely unrelated .... One is essentially a toy, designed for writing small pieces of code, and traditionally used and abused by inexperienced programmers.

The other is a scripting language for web browsers.

Comment: @SaymoinSam you are right

Comment: Please choose a language. Tag-spamming is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want an array of numbers that show up more than once. And that is exactly what I did.

New Updates: I went away and realized some errors and came back to fix. Plus, I was hoping I could make it even faster and shorter.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

<p>Input: [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6]</p>
Output: <p id="demo1"></p>


<p>Input: [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,9]</p>
Output: <p id="demo2"></p>


<script>

function uniqueNumbers(numbers) {
  return [... new Set(numbers)];
}

var findDuplicates = function(numbers) {
 
    var final_array = [];
 
    //no duplicates
    
    var no_duplicate_array = uniqueNumbers(numbers);
    
    //frequency count array to count frequency
    
    var frequency_table = [];
    
    for (var i = 0 ; i < no_duplicate_array.length; i++){
    
        var counter = 0;
        
        var foundSomething = false; 
        
        var last_match_index = 0; //for optimization due to array being sorted
    
            for (var j = last_match_index; j < numbers.length; j++) {
             
                if (no_duplicate_array[i] === numbers[j]) {
                
                 last_match_index = j + 1;
                    
                    foundSomething = true; 
                
                 counter++;
                
                }
                
                //for optimization. If found a number
                //and all of sudden, stopped seeing the
                //number then that's all of it. 
                //move on to the next next number.
                if (foundSomething &&
                 no_duplicate_array[i] !== numbers[j]) {
                    
                 break;
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
            //for further optimization. 
            if (counter > 1) { //item repeats - meaning more than 1
             final_array.push(no_duplicate_array[i]);

         } 
          
    }

    return final_array;
};

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = findDuplicates([1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6]);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = findDuplicates([1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,9]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution involves using JS object as a hashmap.

We create a new empty array `repeatedItems`, as this array will store values that are repeated.

As the input array loops, we're checking if each item exists as a property of the object `itemsMap`. If it doesn't exist, use that item as key value on `itemsMap` and set it to true. This makes it so that when the next item with the same value is visited, it will return a true value and add that item to `repeatedItems`

```js
const array = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];

function findRepeated(array) {
  const itemsMap = {};
  const repeatedItems = [];

  array.forEach((item) => {
    if (!itemsMap[item]) { 
      itemsMap[item] = true;
    } else {
      repeatedItems.push(item);
    }
  });

  return repeatedItems;
}

console.log(findRepeated(array)); // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: hi sorry i edited the question because i made a mistake what i meant is to get an array of the repeated values only

Comment: @sammy no problem, I updated the solution to return repeated items

Answer (score 0):

```js
function uniqueNumbers(numbers) {
  return [... new Set(numbers)];
}
console.log(uniqueNumbers([1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let findDuplicates = arr => arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) != index)

console.log(findDuplicates([1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6])); // all duplicates
console.log([... new Set(findDuplicates([1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6]))]);// only duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this answer i think it's working

```
var findRepeated = function(nums) {
array1 = []
array2 = []
for (var i = 0 ; i < nums.length ; i++){
    if(nums[i] == nums[i+1])
        array1.push(nums[i])
}
for(var i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++){
    if(array1[i] != array1[i+1]){
        array2.push(array1[i])
    }

}
return array2;
```

}